# jQuery problem with form field validation

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I have built a form with two input fields of type "date" and two select boxes for selecting a time window. If all fields are filled out correctly, a "Continue" button should be displayed. However, this already appears when the second "date" field is filled out. IDs etc. are all correct. Any ideas what it could be?

First of all, here is the structure:

```
      <div class="terminauswahl reiter reiter2">
    <div class="formgrid">
      <div>
        <label>Datum<span>*</span></label>
        <input type="date" id="datum" name="datum">
        <span class="errormsg"></span> </div>
      <div>
        <label>Abgabezeit<span>*</span></label>
        <select id="zeit" name="zeit"/>
          <option value="" selected disabled>Bitte wählen</option>
          <option value="08:00 - 08:30">08:00 - 08:30</option>
          <option value="09:00 - 09:30">09:00 - 09:30</option>
          <option value="10:00 - 10:30">10:00 - 10:30</option>
          <option value="11:00 - 11:30">11:00 - 11:30</option>
          <option value="12:00 - 12:30">12:00 - 12:30</option>
          <option value="13:00 - 13:30">13:00 - 13:30</option>
          <option value="14:00 - 14:30">14:00 - 14:30</option>
          <option value="15:00 - 15:30">15:00 - 15:30</option>
          <option value="16:00 - 16:30">16:00 - 16:30</option>
          <option value="17:00 -17:30">17:00 -17:30</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="formgrid">
      <div>
        <label>Alternatives Datum<span>*</span></label>
        <input type="date" id="altDatum" name="altDatum">
        <span class="errormsg"></span> </div>
      <div>
        <label>Alternative Abgabezeit<span>*</span></label>
        <select id="altZeit" name="altZeit">
          <option value="" selected disabled>Bitte wählen</option>
          <option value="08:00 - 08:30">08:00 - 08:30</option>
          <option value="09:00 - 09:30">09:00 - 09:30</option>
          <option value="10:00 - 10:30">10:00 - 10:30</option>
          <option value="11:00 - 11:30">11:00 - 11:30</option>
          <option value="12:00 - 12:30">12:00 - 12:30</option>
          <option value="13:00 - 13:30">13:00 - 13:30</option>
          <option value="14:00 - 14:30">14:00 - 14:30</option>
          <option value="15:00 - 15:30">15:00 - 15:30</option>
          <option value="16:00 - 16:30">16:00 - 16:30</option>
          <option value="17:00 -17:30">17:00 -17:30</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And here's the check with jQuery:

```
if ($('#datum').val() !== '' 
    && $('#zeit').val() !== '' 
    && $('#altDatum').val() !== '' 
    && $('#altZeit').val() !== '') {
  $('.tc2-grid').children('.btn-next').show();
  $('.tc2-grid').addClass('tc-grid-active');
} else {
  $('.tc2-grid').children('.btn-next').hide();
  $('.tc2-grid').removeClass('tc-grid-active');
}

}
$('#datum, #zeit, #altDatum, #altZeit').on('change', function() {
  checkFormCompletion();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your drop downs are never `===''`.

You're using strict comparison `!==` - but your `.val()` is not `''`, it's `null`.  Some simple debugging will show you the actual values:

console.log($('#datum').val())
console.log($('#zeit').val())
console.log($('#altDatum').val())
console.log($('#altZeit').val())

and

console.log($('#datum').val() === '')
console.log($('#zeit').val() === '')
console.log($('#altDatum').val() === '')
console.log($('#altZeit').val() === '')

`$("#zeit").val() === null` and `null !== ''`, so your test is always true.

Easy fix is to add `||""` after each .val on a select where it could be null (or change your first `option` so it's not disabled).

```js
function checkFormCompletion() {

  //console.log($('#datum').val())
  //console.log($('#zeit').val())
  //console.log($('#altDatum').val())
  //console.log($('#altZeit').val())

  if ($('#datum').val() !== '' &&
    ($('#zeit').val() || '') !== '' &&
    $('#altDatum').val() !== '' &&
    ($('#altZeit').val() || '') !== '') {
    $('.tc2-grid').children('.btn-next').show();
    $('.tc2-grid').addClass('tc-grid-active');
  } else {
    $('.tc2-grid').children('.btn-next').hide();
    $('.tc2-grid').removeClass('tc-grid-active');
  }

}

$('#datum, #zeit, #altDatum, #altZeit').on('change', function() {
  checkFormCompletion();
});

 $('.tc2-grid').children('.btn-next').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="terminauswahl reiter reiter2">
  <div class="formgrid">
    <div>
      <label>Datum<span>*</span></label>
      <input type="date" id="datum" name="datum">
      <span class="errormsg"></span> </div>
    <div>
      <label>Abgabezeit<span>*</span></label>
      <select id="zeit" name="zeit">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Bitte wählen</option>
        <option value="08:00 - 08:30">08:00 - 08:30</option>
        <option value="09:00 - 09:30">09:00 - 09:30</option>
        <option value="10:00 - 10:30">10:00 - 10:30</option>
        <option value="11:00 - 11:30">11:00 - 11:30</option>
        <option value="12:00 - 12:30">12:00 - 12:30</option>
        <option value="13:00 - 13:30">13:00 - 13:30</option>
        <option value="14:00 - 14:30">14:00 - 14:30</option>
        <option value="15:00 - 15:30">15:00 - 15:30</option>
        <option value="16:00 - 16:30">16:00 - 16:30</option>
        <option value="17:00 -17:30">17:00 -17:30</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="formgrid">
    <div>
      <label>Alternatives Datum<span>*</span></label>
      <input type="date" id="altDatum" name="altDatum">
      <span class="errormsg"></span> </div>
    <div>
      <label>Alternative Abgabezeit<span>*</span></label>
      <select id="altZeit" name="altZeit">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Bitte wählen</option>
        <option value="08:00 - 08:30">08:00 - 08:30</option>
        <option value="09:00 - 09:30">09:00 - 09:30</option>
        <option value="10:00 - 10:30">10:00 - 10:30</option>
        <option value="11:00 - 11:30">11:00 - 11:30</option>
        <option value="12:00 - 12:30">12:00 - 12:30</option>
        <option value="13:00 - 13:30">13:00 - 13:30</option>
        <option value="14:00 - 14:30">14:00 - 14:30</option>
        <option value="15:00 - 15:30">15:00 - 15:30</option>
        <option value="16:00 - 16:30">16:00 - 16:30</option>
        <option value="17:00 -17:30">17:00 -17:30</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class='tc2-grid'>
    <div class='btn-next'>
      continue
    </div>
  </div>
```